# Better approach for handwriting recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

I am trying to write an ANN in python for handwriting recognition by mouse movements. ( like identify characters we draw in paint app n convert it to text)

The question might seem that I haven't done my homework, but I am *not * looking for image datasets for handwritten characters.( at least that's what I've figured out so far)

Is there any database for such (array or co-ordinates corresponding to each character) inputs? If not, how can I create this database from existing ones like MNIST?

Currently, I have written a script to generate my own database because I could not find any. But it seems a very tedious task to generate a good database. 
I am a beginner in ML. Could somebody point me in *right direction* upon how else can we do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to get a list of pixel co-ordinates from an image of a character ?  I'm not sure what language you might be using, but in Mathematica this entire list would be returned by: Position[ImageData@Binarize@myCharacterImage, 0]

Comment: I've already written a script in python which returns a list of points (x,y) on button-1 click (left click). (As we draw in paint, we keep left click pressed ) ..... I'll have to draw all the characters of the keyboard in order to generate the training data, Which is tedious. So, I am interested if any standard such databse already exists?

Comment: For example, you might consider automatically converting an existing dataset, for instance the NMIST digits you mention, using something like the above function applied to every character image file. It would scale to thousands of images quite easily.

Comment: Do a google image search for handwritten characters and you will get a lot of examples.

Comment: First, I don't know how to sample those data. Even if I do it, my array ( obtained from the image) will contain entries from left to right scanning of the image. I want entries according to user strokes, not those obtained by left to right ( n up-down) scanning of the image sample. Could you suggest a way to get entries as user strokes them?

Comment: I.e. Entries as per user hand moves while writing a character.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your needs. There appears to be some work on stroke order on Chinese characters.  http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Stroke_Order_Project

Comment: @image_doctor : thanks. You are awesome. :)
Though I'll still need some help for Roman script.